# SSH Tunnel Error: channel 3: open failed: administratively prohibited:

Tags: firefox, ssh-tunneling

The goal is to enable Firefox (on Ubuntu 16.04) to remotely ssh-tunnel and administer the home router (Asus Merlin Linux firmware).  The command:

```
ssh -D localhost:3000 user@myfqdn.asuscomm.com
```

connects a BASH terminal to the SSH server (on the router).

Firefox network settings was configured per [instructions](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=723025):

[image]

Attempts to tunnel traffic through browser (http://www.whatismyip.com) return "unable to connect" and BASH returns multiple instances:

> channel 3: open failed: administratively prohibited:

What is the root cause of the message above and what is the corrective action?

Router (SSH Server) Configuration:

- SSH hosted Asus router with Optware installed
- unable to locate [sshd_config](https://serverfault.com/a/535425) `find . | grep -i sshd_config`

Comment: Instead of `find . | grep ...`, which searches for your current (arbitrary) directory, use `find / ...`.

Comment: @JeffSchaller  Thank you for commenting.   Before executing the find commend, the command `cd /` was executed.   If you can provide the exact command, I can can try it and post the results for you

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to admin the router (which allows admin only on the local side) from an external network? Or are you trying to proxy all your firefox traffic through a tunnel?

Comment: @gatorback, I'd suggest `find / -name sshd_config`

Comment: @user1794469 In the future I would like to admin the remote router from the browser tunnel remotely, however, I am testing the tunnel with the URL www.whatismyip.com, which fails to return a results when the Firefox proxy is engaged.

Comment: @JeffSchaller  `find / -name sshd_config` did not return anything.

Comment: Do you have step 1 working: that you make an ssh connection and leave it running?

Comment: @user1794469  Good question: yes, I am able to ssh in to the remote router

Comment: What OS is the router running? You may need to run the find as root (or admin).